# Smoothing a Bezier Curve to a moving endpoint

Tags: unreal-engine4, bezier, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to do something tricky with Bezier Curves.

What I've got:
[image: (What I've got)]

Basically, I want to move the endpoint/destination while traversing at a constant speed. The example image I've provided is a Ball traversing my Bezier Curve.

The constant speed aspect is working. However, as soon as I move the destination, the ball snaps to the newly-updating Bezier Curve. As a result, the ball appears to move faster, going against what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm still new to using Bezier Curves, so I'm wondering if I'm missing some sort of additional calculation when the target moves.

I'm doing this all with the Blueprint system in Unreal Engine 4.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no programming question is being asked.

Comment: There is, but the post [could have been written a lot better](/help/how-to-ask). Unreal is a programming environment, and Bezier maths is inextricably linked to graphics programming, so even though no code's being shown, this is absolutely a programming question.

Comment: So with that said: what ([mcve]) code are you currently using, and what have you already tried? Because if you move the end point, the ball _has_ to snap to the new curve: that's the path you've given it, and you've updated the path. At the very least you'd need to create a new Bezier curve, _starting at your ball_ that is tangent to the old curve at the ball's position, and then assign that as new path for your ball to travel.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of experimentation, I came up with a solution that works for me:

- Check if the Bezier Curve has changed (I do this by checking if the target has moved)
- If the Bezier Curve has changed, set the ball to travel towards the would-be point on the new Bezier Curve. We get this point by plotting the same distance along the new Bezier Curve.

As a result, the ball now maintains a constant speed without snapping, and will attempt to play catch-up if the Bezier Curve changes.